# Internet Server Error in SDK parse PHP when not uploading files

Tags: php, image, parsing, sdk, internal-server-error

I have a code i'm using in order to upload files. It works right when I upload something, but when I'm not upload nothing, the message "Internal Server Error" appears.

```
if ( isset( $_FILES['image'] ) ) {
        if ( $_FILES['image']['size'] < 600000 ) {
            // save file to Parse
            $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
                       file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
                       $_FILES['image']['name']  );
             $file->save();
         } else {
            echo "El archivo no se adjuntó porque rebasa el tamaño máximo permitido";
         }
     } else {
         $file = "";
     }

//The error remains if i take out this code which saves the image on the Parse database. 
// So the problem is in the code above. 

$report = new ParseObject("Report");
if ( isset( $file ) ) { $report->set("ImageFile", $file); }
$report->save();
```

Comment: hi try at first line if ( count( $_FILES) > 0 ) {   ... } and before you use file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) you need to check if the file exists

Comment: I'm still having the same problem

Comment: what line? the error should give you the error line

Comment: Parse gave me this error. I put this, but it shows me the same: <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could make it work

```
 $isFileExists = (file_exists ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] )) && ($_FILES['image']['error'] != 4);
if ( isset($_FILES['image']) && $isFileExists ) {
    $isGoodSize = ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 600000) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0);

        if ( $isFileExists && $isGoodSize) {

            $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
                       file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
                       $_FILES['image']['name']  );
             $file->save();
         } else {
            echo "No adjuntaste alguna imagen, o no se subió porque rebasa el tamaño máximo permitido";
         }
     }
if ( isset( $file ) ) { $report->set("ImageFile", $file); }
    $report->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this. I didn't test it but you can see the idea

```
$file = "";
if ( !empty($_FILES['image']['name']) ) {
    $isFileExists = file_exists ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] );
    $isGoodSize = ($_FILES['image']['size'] < 600000) && ($_FILES['image']['size'] > 0);

        if ( $isFileExists && $isGoodSize) {

            $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
                       file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
                       $_FILES['image']['name']  );
             $file->save();
         } else {
            echo "El archivo no se adjuntó porque rebasa el tamaño máximo permitido";
         }
     }

$report = new ParseObject("Report");
if ( isset( $file ) ) { $report->set("ImageFile", $file); }
$report->save();
```

Comment: place exit() before the start of the code and see if you still have an error

Comment: The error dissapears. The mistake is in that code, the problem is I don't know which is the mistake

Comment: put die("here") before  $file = ParseFile::createFromData and next step after$file = ParseFile::createFromData   to see where  is en error

Comment: Yeap, the problem is in this code: $file = ParseFile::createFromData( 
        file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ), 
        $_FILES['image']['name']  );
    $file->save();

Comment: and it happens when you NOT specifying file to upload?

Comment: Yes, only when I'm not specifying file to upload

Comment: please do echo print_r($_FILES, true) before $file = ParseFile::createFromData to see the stuff

Comment: ARRAY ( [IMAGE] => ARRAY ( [NAME] => [TYPE] => [TMP_NAME] => [ERROR] => 4 [SIZE] => 0 ) )

Comment: Now works when I not upload a file and crashs when upload a image (with the same advice)

Comment: ok edited again, i removed 3 first lines of  default imge, please try again

Comment: Now again like at first, only works when I upload an image

Comment: impossible, should working fine, anyway you will need to debug it in a spot i cannot see for now why it happens

Comment: It's impossible. I don't know why